# Installing WINDOWS - 7 WITH secondary display enabled from the time of installation

Tags: windows-7, installation, display, external-display

We have MINI ITX motherboard, This board supports multiple display option  VGA, LVDS..For this configuration we prefer only LVDS.
Currently, we are migrating from LINUX to WINDOWS,Initial installation process does not have any hicups. 
However, when the installtion completes and ask for a reboot. The system by default switches to VGA and there is no display on lVDS.
For this we have to connect an VGA display and complete the rest of the installation and set "Duplicate Desktop on Projector" to get the LVDS back.

We definitely do not require any VGA interference during the installation process. Need some guidance fro enabling  /CLONE display mode from the time of installation.

Comment: Please tell us what you have researched and attempted in order to resolve this.

Comment: I have checked all BIOS option in the motherboard ..Also, when i google all the searches ends to "Configuring multiple monitors".. None of speak about during installation.

Comment: Have you looked at [Windows Automated Installation Kit for Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: Just now setuped a AIK,,Will check ,,,,Thanks for teh INFO\